# Need some changes in JavaScript image sources

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img class="lazy" data-src="lazy-image.jpg">
<img class="lazy" data-src="lazy-image.jpg">
<img class="lazy" data-src="lazy-image.jpg">


    const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) =>
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            // set image source only when it is in the viewport
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                const image = entry.target;
                // setting image source from the dataset
                image.src = image.dataset.src;

                // when image is loaded, we do not need to observe it any more
                io.unobserve(image);
            }
        })
    );

    document.querySelectorAll(".lazy").forEach((element) => io.observe(element));
```

This is pure JavaScript code. I find on blog article. This method working fine on my website. i used custom php script. That used smarty theme engine.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((element) => io.observe(element));
```

i targets whole website img tag. Its working that i given.

```
 image.src = image.dataset.src;
```

This img source code. Lazy load working fine. If i used `<img data-src="">` 
when i write new contents. Its not possible to add everytime in code.
Now i want only regular `<img src="">` tag for my images.
There need some changes in javascript code for use regular src.

```
`image.src = image.dataset.src;`
```

↑ this code need some changes for use ↓

```
<img src="">
```

Please anybody help me on this issue? sorry for bad English skills. i hope you understand.
i waiting for your response.
Thank you so much.

Comment: That's not HTML, should be [`<img src="">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Technical_summary). Notice specifically "_... must not have an end tag_".

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change JavaScript img sources? `image.src = image.dataset.src;`

Comment: The real question should be, why not just assign the `src=` in your `<img />` tags to begin with? Bloated.

Comment: I want the img load in src not in data-src.

Comment: But you still want them to lazy-load? I'm not sure if that's possible, as I think the browser will load all the img src automatically. Why can't you write data-src still? I guess it might be possible to use script to move the src= values into data-src as you're loading the page, but I doubt you could guarantee you'll always manage to do this before the browser starts loading the image.

Comment: @StackSlave The point is to only load images as the user scrolls down to see them. If you just used src= then they'd all load immediately.

Comment: I used an custom php Script. When i add an article, its not possible to edit my article Everytime. My website have an editing & content writing dashboard like WordPress. So there automatically used src attribute. When i added an new pictures in my content. Mobileprice24.net this is my website. If you visit, Then you can understand better.

Comment: If possible modify the JavaScript. Then my website all pictures working as lazy load.

Comment: Check this out, maybe it helps you https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/

Comment: Thank you so much.  I already checked the method. Its not working perfectly. I want lazy load for my full website. I find best one that works perfectly in my website. Now only need to change the src type. Then i can use it for full website.